# Missing FROM-clause entry for table in postgres CTE

Tags: postgresql, cte

Using the following data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
    x int
);
CREATE TABLE b (
    y int
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES 
(1), (2);
INSERT INTO b VALUES 
(1), (1), (2), (2) ;
```

I'm trying to query as:

```sql
WITH a_cte AS (
     SELECT min(x) AS min_a
     FROM a
)
SELECT * FROM b 
WHERE b.y <= a_cte.min_a;
```

But am receiving the error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "a_cte"
```

I don't understand the reasoning here, as I thought I'd created the temp table `a_cte` and could freely use it within the scope.

Note - this is on PostgreSQL 14.2

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ no - but I thought that the selection was within the scope of the with statement

Comment: You *really* don't need a CTE here.  `WHERE b.y <= (SELECT MIN(x) FROM a)` is perfectly valid unless you're getting paid by the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand the reasoning here, as I thought I'd created the
> temp table a_cte and could freely use it within the scope

You are facing with  `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "a_cte"`  error because you never select from `a_cte`.

Use:

```
WITH a_cte AS (
     SELECT min(x) AS min_a
     FROM a
)
SELECT b.* 
FROM b  
inner join a_cte on b.y <= a_cte.min_a
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Ec_MtFek

[WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

*Edit*.

> I don't understand how this is fundamentally different to my usage
> though, just has a join instead of a where. Can you write it so that
> WHERE works please?

As I already mentioned, when using `WITH a_cte AS ()` you need to use `a_cte`.

The where is redundant on your case , it is used on the join condition.

Maybe you are confusing the old join syntax **which I do not recommend**. This is still a join , but written differently

```
WITH a_cte AS (
     SELECT min(x) AS min_a
     FROM a
)
SELECT * FROM b, a_cte
WHERE b.y <= a_cte.min_a;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/uk_98YSX

Comment: thanks - I don't understand how this is fundamentally different to my usage though, just has a join instead of a where. Can you write it so that `WHERE` works please?

Comment: seems I would need `where b.y <= (select min_a from a_cte)`, which works, maybe I just need to read the docs more - I'm not too sure why i need to do this for a where but not a join though

Comment: @baxx check the last Edit part

Comment: It doesn't work for the same reason that `SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.y = a.y` doesn't work, `a` table is not in any `FROM` clause.

Comment: @ErgestBasha thanks, i was using where (rather than join) as in the actual data i was filtering on inequalities (time comparison) rather than exact matches, but that's not represented in the data I gave so clearly (other than the use of `<=`)